# Azure VMSS with Powershell DSC disabled TLS 1.0 cannot download script

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-vm-scale-set, powershell-dsc

I have a DSC script that configures a VMSS on Azure.  Part of the script disables TLS1.0 and TLS1.1 client and server roles.  After disabling, the VMSS cannot download the DSC script in the zip file anymore.  Says it timed out after 29 attempts.  If I enable the TLS protocols, it works again.

Is there a way to make the script download using TLS 1.2?

Currently, this is the ARM configuration for the script extension:

```
"extensionProfile": {
                    "extensions": [
                        {
                            "name": "Microsoft.Powershell.DSC",
                            "properties": {
                                "publisher": "Microsoft.Powershell",
                                "type": "DSC",
                                "typeHandlerVersion": "2.72",
                                "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
                                "forceUpdateTag": "[parameters('dscVmssUpdateTagVersion')]",
                                "settings": {
                                    "configuration": {
                                        "url": "https://mydsc.blob.core.windows.net/dsc/scalesetSetup.zip",
                                        "script": "prepareServer.ps1",
                                        "function": "PrepareServer"
                                    },
                                    "configurationArguments": {
                                        "nodeName": "localhost",
                                        "envName": "[parameters('envName')]",
                                        "buildNumber": "[parameters('buildNumber')]"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way of doing that, move your script into the DSC configuration (or at least the part that disables TLS 1.0\1.1). This way you can solve this chicken\egg dilema.

Comment: it is part of dsc.  however, after it applies, when the VMSS goes to update the next time, it cannot download the dsc script at all to run the update.

Comment: when dsc updates it creates a new node, so this shouldnt be the case

Comment: while it does create new nodes, it updates existing ones as well.  all of mine are same machines with multiple updates applied to them.  as soon as I close off tls, i can't ever update again.

Comment: use script extensión before dsc extensión to enable tls, use dsc to disable tls as the last step of dsc extensión. as you cannot control dsc extensión thats the best i can imagine. start a support ticket about this one

Comment: interesting potential work around.  i may give that a shot and report back how it goes

Answer (score 0):

I have TLS1.0 disabled by DSC and it works well.
The only difference with your template that I have "typeHandlerVersion": "2.26".

Comment: you're able to run the template again against the existing virtual machine without error?

Comment: Yes, I am able to run it again. Also I am able to restart nodes and DSC downloaded from blob storage and applied to nodes during bootup.
I have only one issue after disabling TLS1.0. Cluster widget on portal.azure.com can't connect to cluster to display nodes and applications status. It just displays "Loading". Microsoft support replied, that TLS1.0 is required to widget work correctly.

Comment: I didn't tried it yet. Will wait for TLS1.1 retirement.

Comment: BTW were you able to check DSC logs on SF cluster nodes?
Remember, if you are using resource group deployment script shipped with VS, it will set 4 hours expiration for storage account SAS token where DSC is stored.